apollo-client-maven-plugin: How to flatten fragments in generated models
I'm using the apollo-client-maven-plugin version 7.1.0, and I'm trying to flatten fragments in my response models, but I'm encountering an issue where the fragments are wrapped in a nested object.
Here’s the GraphQL query I’m using:
fragment AuthenticationFragment on SessionInfo {
  role
  sessionGUID
  token
}

mutation loginAsGuest {
    login(
        lang: { key: "FRA" }
    ) {
        ...AuthenticationFragment
    }
}

The expected response (from a GraphQL client like Postman) is:
{
    "data": {
        "login": {
            "role": "XXX",
            "sessionGUID": "XXX",
            "token": "XXXX"
        }
    }
}

However, when using the Apollo Java Client, the response looks like this:
{
    "login": {
      "__typename": "SessionInfo",
      "authenticationFragment": {
        "role": {
          "rawValue": "XXX"
        },
        "sessionGUID": "XXX",
        "token": "XXX"
      }
    }
  }

As you can see, the fields of the AuthenticationFragment are nested inside the authenticationFragment object.
How can I remove the authenticationFragment wrapper and directly flatten the fields (role, sessionGUID, token) into the login object?
I have tried enabling the flattenModels option in my plugin configuration, but it didn’t work as expected.
Any help would be appreciated!
